# Phase when a compiler combines sources

Tags: compiler-construction

Before doing the semantic analysis (including stuff like type checking) I guess it's important to have the WHOLE program (represented via abstract syntax tree or whatever).

In order to have all the information together you have to combine the source files, meta-info of referenced libraries and so on.

How is this combining phase called because "linking" normally refers to putting together stuff that the compiler produced and not the input-files and imported libraries.

Answer (score 2):

A compiler generally compiles a single source file to a single object file.

The source files aren't necessarily all loaded into memory at once. And the object files aren't combined until they are **linked**.

To do the type checking (among other things) the compiler needs to know all the ways this compilation unit references others. In C/C++ that is through header files which are included in the preprocessor.

Comment: I edited your post for readability. Remember SO answers are for human beings to _read_ :) - same goes for the OP though